# doxygenを使用してHTMLとCSSのドキュメントを作りたい

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphviz, document

doxygenを使ってドキュメントを作成しています。
その中でHTMLと CSSのコード内にdoxygenの特殊コマンドを書いても認識してindex.htmlを作成してくれません。
JavaScriptは特殊コマンドを書いて実行するとドキュメントに反映されて関数や変数の説明がindex.htmlに反映されます。
ファイルの拡張子はdoxyfileに書いてるのでファイル自体の認識はしてツリーには出てくれます。
もしHTMLや CSSのドキュメント作成をdoxygenでできる方法があれば教えてほしいです

Comment: HTML/CSSのソースファイルそのものを文書化(例えばプロジェクトの設計文書とかあるいは納品物として？)したいように見受けられますが、それらはdoxygenのサポート言語の中に入っていないようです。[doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/) には `Next to C++, Doxygen also supports C, Python, PHP, Java, C#, Objective-C, Fortran, VHDL, Splice, IDL, and Lex.` の記述があります。また [Doxygen - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) でもHTML/CSSがサポートされているような記述は無いですし、何か別のツールを探した方が良いのでは？ そうした見立てが違うというのなら、もう少しどのような物をどう処理してどんな結果を得たいのかについて詳細な記述をしてみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)